# Limits and the Distributive Property?

Tags: calculus, limits, binary-operations

I am currently  relearning calculus after ages of not having much to do with it, and I'm looking at the proofs for the basic limit laws. I was wondering if there is a "simpler"/ more elegant way of proving them, as opposed to the standard Proofs that use the epsilon-delta definition. The reason I ask is because I noticed the following:

If we let the limit Process be represented by "@", such that the limit of f(X) as X approaches n becomes "n @ f(X)" then the limit laws just become Distributive Property statements.

For instance, the addition law becomes: n @ [ f(X) + g(X) ] = n @ f(X) + n @ g(X)

This leads me to think that there is some way of proving the limit laws using symmetry or set theory or somesuch. Am I correct in this? The way I figure it such a proof might go as follows:

1. Prove that the limit operation belongs to a certain kind of operations
2. Prove that this kind of operations is distributive with respect to the 4 common algebraic operations.

This is blowing my mind. Is there such a proof?

Answer (score 1):

Just some thoughts on limits.

(1).One difficulty is that $f(x)+g(x)$, or $f(x)g(x)$ may have a limit as $x\to 0$ even though $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ do not have limits as $x\to 0.$ That is,it is true that if $a=\lim f(x)$ and $b=\lim g(x)$ (as $x\to 0$) then $f(x)+g(x)\to a+b$ and $f(x)g(x)\to a b$, but the reverse implication does not hold. So the distributive property is "one-directional."

(2).It is often easier to use the following  equivalent def'n of $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=y$  : That $y$ is the unique point such that for every neighborhood  $U$ of $y$, the set $\{n: x_n\not \in U\}$ is finite.

(3).A set-theoretic topologic equivalent of $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=y$ is $\{y\}=\cap_{n\in N}$ Cl$(\{x_m:m\geq n\}).$

(4).You may see $T=\lim \sup_{n\to \infty}S$ when $S=(S_n)_{n\in N}$ is a sequence of sets. $T$ is the set of all,and, only ,those $x$ such that $\{n : x\in S_n\}$ is infinite. That is,$T=\cap_{n\in N}\cup_{m\geq n}S_m.$

Comment: As far as the first comment goes, I think that may be why when we see the limit laws in calculus, they have the caveat "Provided that the limits exist. " I am not familiar with topology except extremely vaguely (like I said, I'm sat relearning calc) so I cannot comment on the other things.

Comment: On a related site about math education, a teacher asked what to do about students' tendencies to apply the "Universal Distributive Law". e.g  $\sqrt {x+y}=\sqrt x+\sqrt y, $ or $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3, $ or even $A^{B+C}=A^B+A^C$...:)